# How to get the height and width of an iframe

Tags: javascript

How to get the height and width of an `iframe`, executing a script from
outside the `iframe`?

I want to find its dimensions.

Javascript solutions welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Using pure javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].getAttribute('width');
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].getAttribute('height');
```

Comment: This will only work if you set `width` and `height` before.

Answer (score 1):

`getBoundingClientRect` returns an object with the following keys: `left`, `top`, `right` ,`bottom`, `x`, `y`, `width` und `height`.

```js
const { width, height } = document.querySelector("iframe").getBoundingClientRect();

console.log(width, height);
```

```html
<p>Example for iframe dimensions</p>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
```